# AUCTeX Info Files in OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew, auctex

I have Emacs installed from http://emacsformacosx.com/ and AUCTeX installed from homebrew. I used the option `--with-emacs=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` while installing AUCTeX. I am able to successfully load `auctex.el` and `preview-latex.el` using:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp")
(require 'tex-site)
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
```

However, AUCTeX's info files seem to be unavailable. I checked `/usr/share/info/` and `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/info/`, the two default locations the info program searches for info files, but those related to AUCTeX are absent.

I looked at the AUCTeX tarball from the [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download-for-macosx.html) and it does have the info files under `doc/`, which the INSTALL notes claim should be automatically installed during the installation process.

So what I am asking is:

1. Does homebrew install the info files for AUCTeX? If yes, where are they located?
2. If homebrew does not install the necessary info files, how can I copy them over from the source to the above mentioned directories. I guess I need to gzip them, so should I just include everything under the `doc/` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

homebrew removes info files when installing packages.  You can force homebrew to keep info files by setting `$HOMEBREW_KEEP_INFO`(as documented in `man brew`).

Set the environment variable `$HOMEBREW_KEEP_INFO` and re-install AUCTeX.  Since you are already using homebrew, I'd suggest to also install Emacs from homebrew:

```
$ brew uninstall auctex
$ brew cleanup
$ export HOMEBREWW_KEEP_INFO=1
$ brew install emacs --cocoa --srgb
$ brew install auctex
```

You should now see AUCTeX info files in `C-h i`.

You may also want to consider installing AUCTeX via `package.el` (`M-x package-install auctex`).

Comment: Just as an update, I went with the package.el option and it worked out fine.